# Screen not moving correctly when keyboard moves up - android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, adjustpan

I´m making an android application in Xamarin and the code below is the axml for the login window. But the problem is when I touch the password field the layout doesn´t move up so I can see the "innskráning" button (the sign in button), I´ve tried making everything relativeLayout and changed a lot in this but nothing works. I also have in my androidManifest file: android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"

Can anybody please help me, I´ve spent so many hours on this.

Thanks in Advance.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        p1:id="@+id/scrollView"
        p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
        p1:layout_height="match_parent"
        p1:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout
            p1:orientation="vertical"
            p1:layout_width="match_parent"
            p1:layout_height="match_parent"
            p1:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            p1:background="#FFFFFF">
            <ImageView
                p1:src="@drawable/advania"
                p1:layout_width="300dp"
                p1:layout_height="180dp"
                p1:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                p1:id="@+id/imageView1"
                p1:layout_gravity="center"
                p1:layout_centerInParent="true"
                p1:background="#FFFFFF" />
            <RelativeLayout
                p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                p1:layout_height="match_parent"
                p1:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                p1:background="#FFFFFF"
                p1:gravity="center">
                <EditText
                    p1:layout_width="230dp"
                    p1:layout_height="42dp"
                    p1:padding="10dp"
                    p1:id="@+id/userName"
                    p1:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    p1:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                    p1:layout_marginTop="3.3dp"
                    p1:hint="Notendanafn"
                    p1:textColor="#000"
                    p1:textSize="14dp"
                    p1:typeface="normal"
                    p1:textStyle="normal"
                    p1:drawableRight="@drawable/iconusername"
                    p1:fontFamily="HelveticaNeue" />
                <EditText
                    p1:inputType="textPassword"
                    p1:layout_width="230dp"
                    p1:layout_height="42dp"
                    p1:padding="10dp"
                    p1:layout_below="@id/userName"
                    p1:id="@+id/password"
                    p1:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    p1:layout_marginTop="18.8dp"
                    p1:textColor="#000"
                    p1:textSize="14dp"
                    p1:textStyle="normal"
                    p1:typeface="sans"
                    p1:drawableRight="@drawable/iconkey"
                    p1:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                    p1:hint="Lykilorð"
                    p1:fontFamily="HelveticaNeue" />
                <Button
                    p1:text="Innskráning"
                    p1:layout_width="230dp"
                    p1:layout_height="42dp"
                    p1:layout_below="@id/password"
                    p1:id="@+id/logIn"
                    p1:layout_marginTop="21.7dp"
                    p1:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    p1:enabled="true"
                    p1:textSize="14dp"
                    p1:typeface="normal"
                    p1:textStyle="normal"
                    p1:fontFamily="HelveticaNeue"
                    p1:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext_login" />
                <TextView
                    p1:text="Version x.x.x"
                    p1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    p1:layout_height="22.2dp"
                    p1:layout_below="@id/logIn"
                    p1:id="@+id/versionText"
                    p1:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    p1:layout_marginTop="20.0dp"
                    p1:layout_marginRight="0.8dp"
                    p1:fontFamily="HelveticaNeue" />
                <TextView
                    p1:text="Advania"
                    p1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    p1:layout_height="22.2dp"
                    p1:layout_below="@id/logIn"
                    p1:id="@+id/textView1"
                    p1:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    p1:layout_marginTop="50.0dp"
                    p1:layout_marginRight="0.8dp"
                    p1:fontFamily="HelveticaNeue" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used **AdjustResize | StateHidden** in the Activity it self
I had **AdjustResize** earlier and it gave me the same problem, but after adding **StateHidden** it worked

```
[Activity(Label = "MainActivity", Theme = "@style/NoActionBar", MainLauncher = true, WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.StateHidden | SoftInput.AdjustResize, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
   public class MainActivity : Activity
{}
```